# how to match full pattern in a string having non english words

Tags: php, regex, encoding, joomla1.5

```
$text="meeus meeùs";
```

I am using the following code to find exact substring mee if any.but since above string contains a dutch word so its failing in that case.that is it should replace the word in the $text string only when it matches the full pattern.

```
$text = preg_replace('/\bmee\b/u', ' ', $text);
```

**Current Output**:meeus mee

**Desired Output**:meeus meeùs

Comment: What does the `str_replace_word()` do?

Comment: @user2935196 don't know what is `str_replace_word ` but `preg_replace('/\bmee\b/u', ' ', $text);` works fine.

Comment: @AmalMurali it finds and replaces the word.

Comment: @anubhava i tried preg_replace also but as i mentioned its not working for non english words

Comment: If I understand well, you want to replace all words that contains "mee"?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte i want to replace all 'mee' with space

Comment: And if "mee" is part of another word?

Comment: @user2935196: Have tried: `preg_replace('/\bmee/u', ' ', $text);` (without word boundary)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte i have a string which contains different words along with non english words,i want to remove all 'mee' words.

Comment: @anubhava thanks again for the reply,ya i tried that also but not working.

Comment: Or may be just: `preg_replace('/mee/u', ' ', $text);`

Comment: @anubhava ya that also not working

Answer (score 1):

Which php version are you using? According to [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refwordboundaries.html) (select PHP in the drop down) PHP supports Unicode on word boundaries since version 5.3.4.

So if it is not working for you, you probably have an older version, where `\b` is ASCII based.

Comment: And your PHP version? According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joomla) the support for Joomla 1.5 ended over a year ago.

Comment: There is your problem. In this PHP version `\b` is ASCII based, so it detects a word boundary between "e" and "ù".

Comment: If you want to use this feature, you should think about updating your environment. I don't know a good workaround.